# Comparing timer and text file

Tags: vb.net, text, time, comparison

I am very new to VB ( not my specialization ) I am searching and trying to find a comparison command for the log text file of my exe.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


    Dim Findstring = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\JBP-Admin\Desktop\Pugad\Mobile Support\catch.txt")
    Dim Lookfor As String = showdat.Text

    If Findstring.Contains(Lookfor) Then
        MsgBox("Found: " & Lookfor)


    End If



End Sub

Public Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DateAndTime.Tick
    DateAndTime.Start()
    ' Me.Text = DateAndTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
    showdat.Text = Format(Now, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles showdat.Click
```

Comment: There will not be anything in your text box at Form.Load. The Timer.Tick that fills the text box will not have ticked until Form.Load has completed.

Comment: Hi Mary, Its okay that it will be nothing to show because I want to check inside of the catch.txt if there is an '==' to the now time. Is that possible that I can compare my 'now' time inside of the catch.txt?

Comment: The double equals sign (==) is the comparison operator in C# . In vb.net the comparison and assignment operators are the same. Just a single equals (=) and the meaning is determined by context.

Comment: Yes you can search your file for the current datetime but it is silly to dump the contents of a file and search it for an empty string in the form load.

Comment: Actually I wont dump the file, because what I do really want here is that If catch.txt will find >= time now then it will close an exe file then re-open it. Can you help me with regards to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move the code from `Form1_Load` to the Timer Tick event handler and the `DateAndTime.Start` to `Form1_Load`:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    DateAndTime.Start()

End Sub

Public Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DateAndTime.Tick
    Dim Findstring = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\JBP-Admin\Desktop\Pugad\Mobile Support\catch.txt")
    Dim Lookfor As String = Format(Now, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")

    showdat.Text = Lookfor

    If Findstring.Contains(Lookfor) Then
        MsgBox("Found: " & Lookfor)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this! but now I want to check 'catch.txt' if it will equal to the latest time now. Is that possible? Then it will show new TIME IS FOUND then it will try to check again if there will be new updated time. Sorry for not good in english

Comment: That's what this code does, every time the timer ticks, it updates the `Lookfor` string with the current time and checks if the `catch.txt` file contains that string.

Comment: WOW! ill try it .. then if there will be an update it will prompt again? I will give it a try!

Comment: I tried adding a proc to kill a process once it found the desired time is it correct?

Comment: Yes, you can certainly do that. Hopefully this answer has gotten you closer to your goal. You can mark this question as answered using the checkmark to the left of the answer and post a new question about any other problem you run into.

Comment: This really helps me! Thank you so much I just need 1 more step to finish it, looking forward hearing from you again!

Comment: Glad I could help. You can post a new question with your updated code and the next problem you are working on.